# Replace string values in R

Tags: r

It's a pretty simple question but I couldn't find a satisfactory solution.

I have 2 vectors:

```
AA <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF")
AASIN <- c("X", "Y", "R", "Z", "T", "G")
```

That should be used for transformation by a specific set of rules:

> AAA = X, BBB = Y, CCC = R, DDD = Z, EEE = T, FFF = G

Now, I want to take a third vector:

```
BB <- c("BBB", "EEE", "FFF")
```

And transform it to:

"Y", "T", "G"

I'm using R and tried a for loop with `gsub` that didn't work:

```
for (i in 1:length(B)) {
    B <- gsub("AAA", "X", B)
    B <- gsub("BBB", "Y", B)
    B <- gsub("CCC", "R", B)
    B <- gsub("DDD", "Z", B)
    B <- gsub("EEE", "T", B)
    B <- gsub("FFF", "G", B)
}
```

I've also tried `gsubfn`:

```
B <- gsubfn(list("AAA" = "X", "BBB" = "Y", "CCC"= "R", "DDD" = "Z", "EEE" = "T", "FFF" = "G"), B)
```

And `mgsub`:

```
B <- mgsub(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF"), c("X", "Y", "R", "Z", "T", "G"), B)
```

But none seem to do the work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Make a named vector, then do subset with name. This is a duplicated post, I will try to find. something like: `myV <- c(AAA = X, BBB = Y, CCC = R, DDD = Z, EEE = T, FFF = G)` then `myV[ "BBB"]` will give you "Y".

Comment: The code which you shared worked for me with a small change.  The vector which you want to change is stored as BB but vector used in for loop is B.  Once you make this change, it gives the desired output.

Comment: Try this: `myV <- setNames(c("X", "Y", "R", "Z", "T", "G"), c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF")); BB <- c("BBB", "EEE", "FFF"); myV[ BB ]` gives:  `"Y" "T" "G" `